# Spartacus - accessing user object from PDP page of Spartacus?

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

I am new to SPA and I am trying to extend the PDP to send certain data to an external API using a button click.

I have been able to retrieve the product object using the `ProductDetailsOutlets` from `@spartacus/storefront` in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductDetailOutlets } from '@spartacus/storefront';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'wishlistStore';

  pdpOutlets = ProductDetailOutlets;
}
```

The `app.component.html` looks like this.

```
<cx-storefront></cx-storefront>

<ng-template [cxOutletRef]="pdpOutlets.SUMMARY" let-product>
    <!-- {{ product | json }} -->
    <app-wishlist-button [productDetails]="product"></app-wishlist-button>
</ng-template>
```

Question here is there a way to access/retrieve the currently logged in user object using the above approach in Spartacus and how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to access the logged in user data in in Spartacus 3.4 would be by using the `get()` method in the `UserAccountFacade`.

In your `app-wishlist-button` component you can add the following code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '@spartacus/core';
import { UserAccountFacade } from '@spartacus/user/account/root';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wishlist-button',
  templateUrl: 'wishlist-button.component.html',
})
export class WishlistButtonComponent {
  user$: Observable<User> = this.userAccountService.get();

  constructor(protected userAccountService: UserAccountFacade) {}
}
```

You will get an Observable with the user data. You can then either subscribe to it in your Typescript file:

```js
onClick() {
 this.user$.subscribe((user: User) => {
  // You can access user here
 });
}
```

or use it in your html:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async as user">
 <button (click)="onClick(user)">Do Action</button>
</ng-container>
```